# Postgres don't write log

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

After restarting PostgreSQL the log file has stopped being written.

Only the following log appears.

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1351) running in data directory "/var/lib/pipelinedb/9.5"?
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1351) running in data directory "/var/lib/pipelinedb/9.5"?
LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
```

Comment: Like it says, the rest of the log output is somewhere else. Did you look in `/var/lib/pipelinedb/9.5/log/`?

Comment: really the log's are inside `/var/lib/pipelinedb/9.5/log/`, but how change to 'var/log/pipelinedb/`

Comment: There are many configuration options explained in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHERE). You can set the log file location via `log_directory` and `log_filename`.

Comment: I changed, it worked, started to log as I want.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you already have a server instance running. Try to connect with `psql` or use `ps aux | grep -i postgres` to inspect this.
If another server instance is running, don't `kill -9` because you can corrupt your data. Instead do:

```
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pipelinedb/9.5 stop -m fast
```

After this you should start your server properly.

Comment: I did this, and started as follows. but occurred the same error.

`pipeline-ctl -D /var/lib/pipelinedb/9.5 -l /var/log/pipelinedb/pipelinedb.log start
`

Comment: So, ensure the pid inside postmaster.pid (1351) exists and remove the file if don't.

Comment: my postmarster.pid  contains

`2077
/var/lib/pipelinedb/9.5
1494246800
5432
/tmp
*
  5432001    655360`

And the ps aux show me pid 2077, so I think postmaster is right.